# Get updated height of image within Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

so I have a large image that I'm drawing onto my canvas.

```
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

I'm trying to use the images height and width to center it within the canvas, but when I do that, it does not work because img.naturalHeight, clientHeight, and height all give me the original pictures height of more than 5000 pixels. But I instead need the height of the image after its drawn onto the canvas otherwise when I position with 5000 pixels from the left or the top it goes way out of the canvas' viewport.

If anyone has any insight they could share I would be very grateful. Thanks guys!

Comment: Once the image is drawn into the canvas, that drawing becomes a part of the canvas, undifferentiated from anything else that had been previously drawn to the canvas.

Comment: Based on how you're using `.drawImage()`, the drawn width and height are `canvas.width / 2` and `canvas.height / 2` because that's what you told the function to size it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the target location to draw an image into a canvas such that the image is centered and not resized, you would use something like:

```js
let x = (canvas.width - img.width) / 2;
let y = (canvas.height - img.height) / 2;
context.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

If you want to draw the image both resized and centered, you'd use something like:

```js
let width = 100;
let height = 100;
let x = (canvas.width - width) / 2;
let y = (canvas.height - height) / 2;
context.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
```

See [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).